# Retreive the chat history of a single person using realm

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to make chat app, where I am storing the chat history in the database using realm. I am storing the User's id of mine and other person id into the database. How can I get the chat history of mine and other person data? This is the query I am using but I am getting only the my chat not the other ones .

```
chathistorylist = chatrealm.where(Chat_history_pojo.class)
                     .equalTo("senderid", Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()))
                     .equalTo("receiverid", getIntent().getStringExtra("rid"))
                     .findAll();
```

And below is the data i am storing the message i have sent to other person

```
chatrealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
chatrealm.beginTransaction();
Chat_history_pojo chatupdatepojo = chatrealm.createObject(Chat_history_pojo.class);
chatupdatepojo.setSenderid(Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()));
chatupdatepojo.setReceiverid(getIntent().getStringExtra("rid"));                       
chatupdatepojo.setMessage(sendmessgae.getText().toString());
chatupdatepojo.setType("text");
chatrealm.commitTransaction();
chatrealm.close();
sendmessgae.setText("");
```

This is how the i am storing of the other person message into database

```
chatrealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
chatrealm.beginTransaction();
Chat_history_pojo chatupdatepojo = chatrealm.createObject(Chat_history_pojo.class);

chatupdatepojo.setSenderid(getIntent().getStringExtra("rid"));
chatupdatepojo.setReceiverid(Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()));
chatupdatepojo.setMessage(intent.getStringExtra("msg"));
chatupdatepojo.setType("text");
chatrealm.commitTransaction();
chatrealm.close();
```

This is the POJO Class

```
public class Chat_history_pojo  extends RealmObject{
    String senderid;
    String receiverid;
    String message;
    String type;
    String sender_profile;
    String reciever_profile;

    public String getSender_profile() {
        return sender_profile;
    }

    public void setSender_profile(String sender_profile) {
        this.sender_profile = sender_profile;
    }

    public String getReciever_profile() {
        return reciever_profile;
    }

    public void setReciever_profile(String reciever_profile) {
        this.reciever_profile = reciever_profile;
    }

    public String getSenderid() {
        return senderid;
    }

    public void setSenderid(String senderid) {
        this.senderid = senderid;
    }

    public String getReceiverid() {
        return receiverid;
    }

    public void setReceiverid(String receiverid) {
        this.receiverid = receiverid;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume there could be a problem with either `getIntent().getStringExtra("rid")` or `Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: Yup i had fixed now i am getting only one side history that i had sent but i am not getting other user history

Comment: No problem thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
chathistorylist = chatrealm.where(Chat_history_pojo.class)
                     .beginGroup()
                     .equalTo("senderid", Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()))
                     .equalTo("receiverid", getIntent().getStringExtra("rid"))
                     .endGroup()
                     .or()
                     .beginGroup()
                     .equalTo("receiverid", Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext()))
                     .equalTo("senderid", getIntent().getStringExtra("rid"))
                     .endGroup()
                     .findAll();
```

?

Comment: i had completely forgot about the begin group and end group thanks it worked can please tell me that can i use same condition on the deleting ?

Comment: .....the deleting? I thought this question was about obtaining all messages that belong to a particular conversion. Also you generally also want a `findAllSorted("sendDate", Sort.ASCENDING)` or something like that. I have no idea what you are trying to delete.

Comment: i want to delete the conversion also when i clicked the back button but i am using
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        chatrealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.delete(Chat_history_pojo.class);
            }
        });
    } this deleting complete conversion of another uses too but i want to delete particular conversion

Comment: please help me out in this too

Comment: yes this condition should work as long as you call `deleteAllFromRealm()` on it

Comment: but delete allfrom realm is not coming